# How to show full stack trace when an exceptions in pyspark

Tags: pandas, logging, pyspark, log4j2

I have a pyspark program something like this and using applyInPandas

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions 
import pandas_udf, ceil 

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))   

def normalize(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std()) 

df.groupby("id").applyInPandas(normalize, schema="id long, v double").show()
```

errors occured in python code like `applyInPandas` is difficult to retrace. I do get  stack traces for the java code but not from python code. Is there any possibility to configure spark log4j2 configs to get the stack trace from python as well?

Also I have logging like below

```
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger("Logexample")
logger.setLevel(log4jLogger.Level.DEBUG)
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example? You should get the stack-trace etc of exceptions inside a udf by default. In your executor logs. See ***"Common Exceptions / Errors"*** and ***"Stack traces"*** sections in this page: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/development/debugging.html#common-exceptions-errors.

Comment: @Kashyap I dont have any example right now. But is it possible to get the stacktraces of python as well in spark executor with this link?

Answer (score 1):

If the end goal is to apply the standarization shown in your code, you should try to avoid doing it in Pandas. As a general rule of thumb, try to avoid Pandas functions and User Defined Functions (UDF), as they usually break Spark's parallelism and give up all the advantages of a distributed computing system.

In order to accomplish the same transformation you are performing in your code snippet within pyspark, you could leverage pyspark native functions. This is a working example to standarize one column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, stddev

# Get mean and standard deviation of target dataframe 
mean_v, stddev_v = df.select(mean("v"), stddev("v")).first()
# Apply the transformation
df.withColumn("v_scaled", (col("v") - mean_v) / stddev_v)
```

In your case, it seems a bit more complex, as you want to perform this in standarization *for each id and not for the whole column*. In order to accomplish this, you can leverage the a groupby and agg functions, creating a group for each id value, and then aggregating with the required standarization:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, mean, stddev
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)], ("id", "v"))   
df = df.groupBy("id").agg((col(v) - mean(v)) / stddev(v))
```